# Compiling AIR applications with FB4Linux doesn't work

Tags: linux, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I've tried to make Flash Builder work on my Ubuntu 12.04 system but ran into some troubles. After installation of FB4Linux with Eclipse Indigo I ended up with a working Flash IDE. Unfortunately running an AIR Application doesn't seem to work.

I use the Flex SDK 4.5.1 (http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Downloads/) because I thought it might not work with 4.6 (even though I also tried this).

When I run my application, the error message "The directory /home/niq/.flex_sdk_4.5/runtime/air/linux does not exist" appears. I created this directory and copied the AIR SDK into this (2.6) but this doesn't resolve the issue:

"/home/niq/.flex_sdk_4.5/bin/adl: 1: /home/niq/.flex_sdk_4.5/bin_adl: Syntax error: "(" unexpected."

Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex SDK 4.5.1 includes only Win/Mac versions of AIR SDK.  You'll need AIR SDK for Linux.  http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 (AIR SDK 2.6 corresponding to Flex SDK 4.5.1)

Comment: Yes i have tried this. But i don't really know where to put it? The AIR SDK has a subfolder "runtimes/linux" just like the Flex SDK. So is it necessary to put only this folder into ./flex_sdk_4.5/runtime/air/linux? Or the whole folder containing subfolders "bin", "frameworks", "include", "runtime"? I tried both, neither worked for me...

Comment: You need to: (1) `cp -r air_sdk/runtimes/air/linux/* flex_sdk_4.5.1/runtimes/linux` (2) `cp air_sdk/bin/adl flex_sdk_4.5.1/bin/`